# How can I delete duplicate information  with Perl?

Tags: perl

sorry for asking again and again, because lack of knowledge in perl and I am new to programming language. 
my actual problem is I am extracting some nodes from several files and storing in a string and  in that string I have some repeated strings so I need to delete repeated strings. so I tried after your suggestion like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;
use Carp;
  use File::Find;
use File::Spec::Functions qw( canonpath );
use XML::LibXML::Reader;

my @ARGV ="c:/main/work";die "Need directories\n" unless @ARGV;
my $all="<DTCSpecification xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n";
  find(
       sub {
    return unless ( /(_tr\.xml)$/ and -f );
    extract_information();
    return;
    },
  @ARGV
  );
 my $elem;
 sub extract_information {
    my $path = $_;

  if ( my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new( location => $path )) {

         while ( $reader->nextElement( 'university' )) {
                  $elem = $reader->readOuterXml();
         $all=$all.$elem;
        }
   }
    return;
    }
  my $so="</DTCSpecification>";
  $all= $all.$so;

  my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string=>$all);
  my %seen;
    foreach my $uni ( $doc->findnodes('//university') ) 

     my $name = $uni->find('Code');

    print "'$name' duplicated\n",
    $uni->unbindNode() if $seen{$name}++;  # Remove if seen before
     }
   $all = $all.$doc->toString;
    print $all;
```

it printing two times first time with repeated information and second time with without repeated. I tried so much but I can't understanding why its printing two times.how to eliminate printing with repeated information. and also it is removing nodes according to element "code" so its removing node when the code element occurred second time, but  some times I have useful information in second one not at the first appearance. How should I overcome this. could you help me. I am very very sorry for asking again and again and wasting your valuable time.its my humble request.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? There must be something to show if you've been struggling with it for a week

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear why `XML::LibXML::Reader` is needed here. Perhaps a little more information would help in this regard.

Here's how I would do it though:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $file = 'universities.xml';
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $file );

my %seen;
foreach my $uni ( $doc->findnodes('//university') ) {  # 'university' nodes only

    my $name = $uni->find('name');

    print "'$name' duplicated\n",
      $uni->unbindNode() if $seen{$name}++;  # Remove if seen before
}

$doc->toFile('universities.xml'); # Print to file
```

Comment: Should that be `$uni->findvalue('name')` rather than `$uni->find('name')` ?

Comment: @Zaid your code is working when I give one xml file and remove duplicates and write into same file but can you tell me how to read from a file and output print in a string.because I need to use that string for some other process.

Comment: @biji : That's not how to use `toString`. And had you given me the information beforehand about your XML structure I would have advised you accordingly. As a ***quickfix solution only***, `$all = $all . $doc->toString . $so;`.

Comment: @biji : You're changing the question again and again. This is the third time you're revising your requirements and that is *very* annoying. Hopefully next time you will be more clear and transparent about your problem. There is nothing wrong with masking potentially sensitive data, but omitting crucial details will only get you an answer as good as the question you ask.

Comment: @biji : The solution to your problem seems quite obvious (unless you're doing the same mistake of hiding important details). Remove the `if` statement that has the `XML::LibXML::Reader` in it.

Comment: @Zaid As you siad I removed if statement but still there is a problem it printing two times.

Comment: @biji : That's all the help I can offer you. You've strayed a long way from the original question. You might want to post another question where you *clearly* lay out the details of your problem.

Comment: @zaid thank you very much for your reply and for your valuable time spending for me. I learned alot from you. thanks.